# I want to know about translation functions in theme development

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes, translation

I am confused to use translation functions in theme development, specially with default value.

1. In customizer.php

   ```
      $wp_customize->add_setting('section_title', array(
                   'default' => 'TESTIMONIALS',
                   'transport' => 'postMessage',
                   'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                   ));

               $wp_customize->add_control('section_title',array(
                   'type' => 'text',
                   'label' => __('Title','theme-food'),
                   'section' => 'main_section',
                   'setting' => 'section_title',
                   ));
   ```

   In this line
   'default' => 'TESTIMONIALS',
   which function I will use?
   __ , _e or any other.
2. In main.php file when I echo---------- 
   echo esc_html(get_theme_mod('section_title', __('TESTIMONIALS', 'theme-food'));

'TESTIMONIALS' is default value for 'section_title',
so which function is right to use before default value? __ , _e  or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For default, you don't need to use translate function. If you want you can translate them also. Value for `default` should be a `string`. You will find how to make a string translatable within those links mentioned below and you will get a clear idea on WordPress translation.

value of `default` doesn't initially store on DB.

Important links:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers